# Unable to add the gradient to C3 area-spline chart in Angular6

Tags: angular, typescript, charts, c3.js

i am trying to add the Gradient to my C3 area-spline chart in angular 6.  But i am not able to do so. Is there anyway i can do this in typescript. I tried many solutions which were mentioned in javascript but no luck. 
Also please let me know is there any way possible illustrations of d3 area chart.

Comment: Are you trying to add it to just the background of the chart? Or are you trying to do the actual SVG elements the chart consists of?

Comment: trying to svg elements for the chart